# modx revolution создание TV типа множественный список по имеющимся ID с помощью API

Tags: php, modx, revo

Есть поле типа "Список(множественный выбор)", в качестве разделителя в параметрах ввода используется запятая. Хочу через API задать это поле для документа с айдишником `$id`:

```
$tv = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar',array('id'=>$categoryTV));          
$catsIdsValues = array(1,2,3);
$tv->setValue($id,$catsIdsValues);
$tv->save();
```

Результата нет.
Пробовал ставить разделитель, и пушить туда строкой, через запятую, тоже не получилось. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
В поле стоят возможные значения `a==1||b==2||c==3||d==4||e==5` итд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделитель влияет только на вывод из базы. А в базе эти значения хранятся через `||` - поэтому делайте так: `$tv->setValue($id,implode('||',$catsIdsValues));`